# Issue with feeding arrays of structs as arguments into pthread_create

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, pthreads

I am writing a small stepper motor control program for which I need a separate thread that checks if any of the motors requires an update.

I keep getting stuck in passing my data structure into pthread_create() and modifying the status value of test_motor2. The following code should give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct motor{
    int motor_status; 
} motor;

typedef struct argstruct{
    int *vect;
    struct motor *allmotors;
} args;

void *test(void *arg){

    struct argstruct *arguments = arg;
    int *a_array = arguments->vect;
    a_array[0] = 80;

    // HERE I GET STUCK
    struct motor *motors = arguments->allmotors;
    // set test_motor2 status to 1

}

int main(){

    pthread_t sidethread;

    struct motor test_motor;
    struct motor test_motor2;
    test_motor.motor_status = 0;
    test_motor2.motor_status = 0;

    int a[3];
    a[0] = 8; a[1] = 3; a[2] = 2;

    struct motor *all_motors[2];
    all_motors[0] = &test_motor;
    all_motors[1] = &test_motor2;

    struct argstruct motors_and_a;
    motors_and_a.allmotors = all_motors;
    motors_and_a.vect = a;

    if (pthread_create(&sidethread, NULL, test, (void *)&motors_and_a)){
        printf("Thread could not be started\n");
    }

    pthread_join(sidethread, NULL);

    // Check that a[0] has been set to 80
    printf("a[0]: %d\n", a[0]);
    // Check that test_motor2 status is now 1
    printf("Status of test_motor2: %d\n", test_motor2.motor_status);

}
```

The example works for array a but I am unable to get it working for the motors.

Could you please help me with finding a solution?

Thanks!

Max

Comment: Observation: if you're going to use `struct motor` and `struct argstruct` in the code, there's no reason to use `typedef`.  However, that's 100% tangential to your main question.

Comment: you need a `struct motor **` rather than a `struct motor *`, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

warning the assignment

> ```
>  motors_and_a.allmotors = all_motors;
> ```

is invalid because `all_motors` is a `motor* [2]` not a `motor*` as expected by `motors_and_a.allmotors`, so the uses after have undefined behavior.

You have to give only one *motor** rather than an array of *motor**, or to change the definition of *argstruct* to have `struct motor **allmotors;` and of course its use

Because

> ```
> // HERE I GET STUCK
> struct motor *motors = arguments->allmotors;
> // set test_motor2 status to 1
> ```

I suppose you want :

```
typedef struct argstruct{
    int *vect;
    struct motor ** allmotors; /* MODIFIED */
} args;

void *test(void *arg){

    struct argstruct *arguments = arg;
    int *a_array = arguments->vect;
    a_array[0] = 80;

    struct motor ** motors = arguments->allmotors; /* MODIFIED */

    motors[1]->motor_status = 1; /* MODIFIED */

    return 0;
}
```

The rest is unchanged.

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall m.c -lpthread
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
a[0]: 80
Status of test_motor2: 1
```

execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ valgrind ./a.out
==4083== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4083== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4083== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4083== Command: ./a.out
==4083== 
a[0]: 80
Status of test_motor2: 1
==4083== 
==4083== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4083==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4083==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,160 bytes allocated
==4083== 
==4083== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4083== 
==4083== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4083== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

---

A return is also missing in *test*

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Max you welcome. I encourage you to ask for the max level of warnings when you compile, like I did ( `-pedantic -Wextra -Wall` for gcc, search how to do if you use an other compiler )